# How can I remove watermark in PDF using itext/itextsharp?

Tags: c#, java, pdf, itext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing watermark from a pdf using iTextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768130/removing-watermark-from-a-pdf-using-itextsharp)

We have a PDF file from which we want to remove a watermark programmatically.  We use itextsharp, but any other PDF handling library would be ok for us too.

Comment: Remove the watermark? May I ask why?

Comment: How is the watermark implemented? A transparent image? Do you know how to identify that image?

Comment: @Radu: Watermark was added by mistake, and we do not have te source of the PDF document. This is a temporary solution as future PDFs will have no watermark.

Comment: @errorstacks: Java or C# is fine for us, thanks!

Comment: @Rup: We believe it's a transparent image, but we don't know it 100% sure...

Comment: @antur123 take a look at this link http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/12/how-to-remove-watermarks-from-pdf.html