# how remove every images from pdf Itext 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I added background images in my pdf. After I need remove them.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String DEST = "PDF.pdf";
        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(targetStream),new PdfWriter(DEST));
        MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener();
        PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(listener);
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        parser.processPageContent(pdfDoc.getPage(i));
        }
}


public class MyImageRenderListener implements IEventListener {
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case RENDER_IMAGE:
                  ImageRenderInfo renderInfo = (ImageRenderInfo) data;

                    PdfImageXObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
                    if (image == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                PdfImageXObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
                image.getPdfObject().clear();
        }
}
```

When opening a pdf I get an error.
Pdf: https://dropmefiles.com/Ds2Ic

I need remove two background images(I only need the text with all settings without images)
I want it to be like this:
https://dropmefiles.com/iZHvT

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please attach your full code and PDF to reproduce

Comment: @AlexeySubach Hi,  I did what you said :)

Comment: You should remove the image showing instructions rather than trying to clear PDF objects

Comment: @AlexeySubach Can you tell us more?please! I create a pdf on the server, then the client works with the pdf. And then I send it again to delete the photo.

Comment: Your files aren't available anymore. I guess, though, that using the `PdfCanvasEditor` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40999180/1729265) can easily do what you need to do.