# IText 7 - Remove a PDF layer (OCG)

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I searched in several forums and iText documentation like the [Examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/clone-changing-ocgs) but I can't find out how to remove PDF Layers (OCG) using iText7.

I saw there is a class [OCGRemover](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGRemover.java) of the "xtra" library of iText5 but didn't find that class for iText7.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That class hasn't made it to iText 7 just yet. It's on the backlog so it should be implemented, but I can't make any promises on when we'll deliver this functionality.

Comment: Also, this is probably something that should be part of the PdfSweep add-on, not of the core library.

Comment: Actually I would propose making it a mere example of a more generic content stream editor, just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915789/1729265) a somewhat generic `PdfContentStreamEditor` for iText 5 is used as base for the `TransparentGraphicsRemover` the OP was after.