# Replace text inside a PDF file using iText

Tags: java, pdf, replace, itext

Im using `iText(5.5.13)` library to read a .PDF and replace a pattern inside the file. The problem is that the pattern is not being found because somehow some weird characters appear when the library reads the pdf.

For example, in the sentence :

```
"This is a test in order to see if the"
```

becomes this one when I'm trying to read it:

```
[(This is a )9(te)-3(st)9( in o)-4(rd)15(er )-2(t)9(o)-5( s)8(ee)7( if t)-3(h)3(e )]
```

So if I tried to find and replace `"test"`, no `"test"` word would be found in the pdf and it won't be replaced

here is the code i'm using:

```
public void processPDF(String src, String dest) {

    try {

      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
      PdfArray refs = null;
      PRIndirectReference reference = null;

      int nPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

      for (int i = 1; i <= nPages; i++) {
        PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(i);
        PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
        if (object.isArray()) {
          refs = dict.getAsArray(PdfName.CONTENTS);
          ArrayList<PdfObject> references = refs.getArrayList();

          for (PdfObject r : references) {

            reference = (PRIndirectReference) r;
            PRStream stream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference);
            byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
            String dd = new String(data, "UTF-8");

            dd = dd.replaceAll("@pattern_1234", "trueValue");
            dd = dd.replaceAll("test", "tested");

            stream.setData(dd.getBytes());
          }

        }
        if (object instanceof PRStream) {
          PRStream stream = (PRStream) object;

          byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
          String dd = new String(data, "UTF-8");
          System.out.println("content---->" + dd);
          dd = dd.replaceAll("@pattern_1234", "trueValue");
          dd = dd.replaceAll("This", "FIRST");

          stream.setData(dd.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
      }
      PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
      stamper.close();
      reader.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the iText `PdfCleanUpProcessor` yet?

Comment: I didn't tried yet, could you provide me some steps in order to use it?Tx in advance

Comment: Considering the bounty there appears to be relevant interest in this. Nonetheless, in general text replacement in PDFs is **a** not trivial and **b** subject to restrictions. A fairly generic iText based approach would start by determining the position of the text in question using a custom text extraction strategy, continue by removing the current contents of everything at that position using the `PdfCleanUpProcessor`, and finally drawing the replacement text into the gap. Would an answer to that effect resolve your issue? Or do you have any additional requirements you have not yet mentioned?

Comment: Such *additional requirements* could be a reflow of the following text, i.e. if the replacement is shorter than the original, the following text might be expected to shift left, and if the replacement is longer, the following text might be expected to shift right, probably even into a new line, probably even pushing following paragraphs down, probably even across pages. Please be aware, such requirements would be from hard to impossible to implement in general and would make the question too broad, going beyond an answer here...

Comment: The main focus of my question is the need to know how to remove the weird/¿Random? characters that come up when I read the contents of the PDF. Provided I need to find a set of String patterns to then replace them with some other data
 in the PDF, so if when reading the pdf, I will always get random characters in a predictable way (so far always parenthesis and positve/negative numbers like the example above) or if they could be ~$/# or just any random character.

Comment: Once the weird chars are removed,i would need (as you say) to determine the position of the words that i need to replace using a custom text extraction strategy etc..
For now, i don't need to worry about positioning the text, as I can't even find it properly

Comment: *"I will always get random characters in a predictable way"* - those are not random characters. Parenthesis enclose (sub)strings, these strings and numeric values are in an array (delimited by square brackets) which are argument of a **TJ** operation. From the PDF specification on the **TJ** operator: *If the element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount*. But there are other operators, too, for text showing. Thus, it could look differently.

Comment: @mkl the way I see this, there is still no reply to the OPs question, Is there a way to find a certain string pattern in a pdf and then replace it for some other value? (whether the pdf is simple, whether it's a real-life, complex one) We're also facing issues where when we attempt to replace @ characters for blanks, it just voids the whole pdf.  There just doesn't seem to be a way to do what we're attempting

Comment: @Steven *"the way I see this, there is still no reply to the OPs question, Is there a way to find a certain string pattern in a pdf and then replace it for some other value?"* - you're right, comments only serve for clarification and remarks, a serious reply should be given as an actual answer. *"We're also facing issues where when we attempt to replace @ characters for blanks"* - I'm trying to write up something; don't expect anything early, though. (But "replacing *something* for blanks" could essentially be done by "removing *something*", so you merely need to *find* and *redact*.)

Comment: Salva, @Steven - have you tried the option described in my answer yet?

Comment: Hi @mkl, Salva will be working on this, I've awarded the bounty provided yours is the most elaborated and credible answer to the question, will also accept it the moment we get it working, issue is we're currently finishing an alternative implementation which we started prior to receiving your answer

Comment: Ah, ok.no need to accept beforehand, I was just wondering why there was no echo while there was an early reaction to other answers and comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has already been mentioned in comments and answers, PDF is not a format meant for *text editing*. It is a final format, and information on the flow of text, its layout, and even its mapping to Unicode is optional.

Thus, even assuming the optional information on mapping glyphs to Unicode are present, the approach to this task with iText might look a bit unsatisfying: First one would determine the position of the text in question using a custom text extraction strategy, then continue by removing the current contents of everything at that position using the `PdfCleanUpProcessor`, and finally draw the replacement text into the gap.

In this answer I would present a helper class allowing to combine the first two steps, finding and removing the existing text, with the advantage that indeed only the *text* is removed, *not* also any *background graphics etc.* as in case of `PdfCleanUpProcessor` redaction. The helper furthermore returns the positions of the removed text allowing stamping of replacement thereon.

The helper class is based on the `PdfContentStreamEditor` presented in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915789/1729265). Please use [the version of this class on github](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/PdfContentStreamEditor.java), though, as the original class has been enhanced a bit since conception.

The [`SimpleTextRemover`](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/SimpleTextRemover.java) helper class illustrates what is necessary to properly remove text from a PDF. Actually it is limited in a few aspects:

- It only replaces text in the actual page content streams.

  To also replace text in embedded XObjects, one has to iterate through the XObject resources of the respective page in question recursively and also apply the editor to them.
- It is "simple" in the same way the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` is: It assumes the text showing instructions to appear in the content in reading order.

  To also work with content streams for which the order is different and the instructions must be sorted, and this implies that all incoming instructions and relevant render information must be cached until the end of page, not merely a few instruction at a time. Then the render information can be sorted, sections to remove can be identified in the sorted render information, the associated instructions can be manipulated, and the instructions can eventually be stored.
- It does not try to identify gaps between glyphs that visually represent a white space while there actually is no glyph at all.

  To identify gaps the code must be extended to check whether two consecutive glyphs exactly follow one another or whether there is a gap or a line jump.
- When calculating the gap to leave where a glyph is removed, it does not yet take the character and word spacing into account.

  To improve this, the glyph width calculation must be improved.

Considering your example excerpt from your content stream, though, you these restrictions probably won't hinder you.

```
public class SimpleTextRemover extends PdfContentStreamEditor {
    public SimpleTextRemover() {
        super (new SimpleTextRemoverListener());
        ((SimpleTextRemoverListener)getRenderListener()).simpleTextRemover = this;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Removes the string to remove from the given page of the
     * document in the PDF reader the given PDF stamper works on.</p>
     * <p>The result is a list of glyph lists each of which represents
     * a match can can be queried for position information.</p>
     */
    public List<List<Glyph>> remove(PdfStamper pdfStamper, int pageNum, String toRemove) throws IOException {
        if (toRemove.length()  == 0)
            return Collections.emptyList();

        this.toRemove = toRemove;
        cachedOperations.clear();
        elementNumber = -1;
        pendingMatch.clear();
        matches.clear();
        allMatches.clear();
        editPage(pdfStamper, pageNum);
        return allMatches;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given operation to the cached operations and checks
     * whether some cached operations can meanwhile be processed and
     * written to the result content stream.
     */
    @Override
    protected void write(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, List<PdfObject> operands) throws IOException {
        cachedOperations.add(new ArrayList<>(operands));

        while (process(processor)) {
            cachedOperations.remove(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes any started match and sends all remaining cached
     * operations for processing.
     */
    @Override
    public void finalizeContent() {
        pendingMatch.clear();
        try {
            while (!cachedOperations.isEmpty()) {
                if (!process(this)) {
                    // TODO: Should not happen, so warn
                    System.err.printf("Failure flushing operation %s; dropping.\n", cachedOperations.get(0));
                }
                cachedOperations.remove(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tries to process the first cached operation. Returns whether
     * it could be processed.
     */
    boolean process(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor) throws IOException {
        if (cachedOperations.isEmpty())
            return false;

        List<PdfObject> operands = cachedOperations.get(0);
        PdfLiteral operator = (PdfLiteral) operands.get(operands.size() - 1);
        String operatorString = operator.toString();

        if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString))
            return processTextShowingOp(processor, operator, operands);

        super.write(processor, operator, operands);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to processes a text showing operation. Unless a match
     * is pending and starts before the end of the argument of this
     * instruction, it can be processed. If the instructions contains
     * a part of a match, it is transformed to a TJ operation and
     * the glyphs in question are replaced by text position adjustments.
     * If the original operation had a side effect (jump to next line
     * or spacing adjustment), this side effect is explicitly added.
     */
    boolean processTextShowingOp(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, List<PdfObject> operands) throws IOException {
        PdfObject object = operands.get(operands.size() - 2);
        boolean isArray = object instanceof PdfArray;
        PdfArray array = isArray ? (PdfArray) object : new PdfArray(object);
        int elementCount = countStrings(object);

        // Currently pending glyph intersects parameter of this operation -> cannot yet process
        if (!pendingMatch.isEmpty() && pendingMatch.get(0).elementNumber < processedElements + elementCount)
            return false;

        // The parameter of this operation is subject to a match -> copy as is
        if (matches.size() == 0 || processedElements + elementCount <= matches.get(0).get(0).elementNumber || elementCount == 0) {
            super.write(processor, operator, operands);
            processedElements += elementCount;
            return true;
        }

        // The parameter of this operation contains glyphs of a match -> manipulate 
        PdfArray newArray = new PdfArray();
        for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < array.size(); arrayIndex++) {
            PdfObject entry = array.getPdfObject(arrayIndex);
            if (!(entry instanceof PdfString)) {
                newArray.add(entry);
            } else {
                PdfString entryString = (PdfString) entry;
                byte[] entryBytes = entryString.getBytes();
                for (int index = 0; index < entryBytes.length; ) {
                    List<Glyph> match = matches.size() == 0 ? null : matches.get(0);
                    Glyph glyph = match == null ? null : match.get(0);
                    if (glyph == null || processedElements < glyph.elementNumber) {
                        newArray.add(new PdfString(Arrays.copyOfRange(entryBytes, index, entryBytes.length)));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (index < glyph.index) {
                        newArray.add(new PdfString(Arrays.copyOfRange(entryBytes, index, glyph.index)));
                        index = glyph.index;
                        continue;
                    }
                    newArray.add(new PdfNumber(-glyph.width));
                    index++;
                    match.remove(0);
                    if (match.isEmpty())
                        matches.remove(0);
                }
                processedElements++;
            }
        }
        writeSideEffect(processor, operator, operands);
        writeTJ(processor, newArray);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Counts the strings in the given argument, itself a string or
     * an array containing strings and non-strings.
     */
    int countStrings(PdfObject textArgument) {
        if (textArgument instanceof PdfArray) {
            int result = 0;
            for (PdfObject object : (PdfArray)textArgument) {
                if (object instanceof PdfString)
                    result++;
            }
            return result;
        } else 
            return textArgument instanceof PdfString ? 1 : 0;
    }

    /**
     * Writes side effects of a text showing operation which is going to be
     * replaced by a TJ operation. Side effects are line jumps and changes
     * of character or word spacing.
     */
    void writeSideEffect(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, List<PdfObject> operands) throws IOException {
        switch (operator.toString()) {
        case "\"":
            super.write(processor, OPERATOR_Tw, Arrays.asList(operands.get(0), OPERATOR_Tw));
            super.write(processor, OPERATOR_Tc, Arrays.asList(operands.get(1), OPERATOR_Tc));
        case "'":
            super.write(processor, OPERATOR_Tasterisk, Collections.singletonList(OPERATOR_Tasterisk));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes a TJ operation with the given array unless array is empty.
     */
    void writeTJ(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfArray array) throws IOException {
        if (!array.isEmpty()) {
            List<PdfObject> operands = Arrays.asList(array, OPERATOR_TJ);
            super.write(processor, OPERATOR_TJ, operands);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Analyzes the given text render info whether it starts a new match or
     * finishes / continues / breaks a pending match. This method is called
     * by the {@link SimpleTextRemoverListener} registered as render listener
     * of the underlying content stream processor.
     */
    void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        elementNumber++;
        int index = 0;
        for (TextRenderInfo info : renderInfo.getCharacterRenderInfos()) {
            int matchPosition = pendingMatch.size();
            pendingMatch.add(new Glyph(info, elementNumber, index));
            if (!toRemove.substring(matchPosition, matchPosition + info.getText().length()).equals(info.getText())) {
                reduceToPartialMatch();
            }
            if (pendingMatch.size() == toRemove.length()) {
                matches.add(new ArrayList<>(pendingMatch));
                allMatches.add(new ArrayList<>(pendingMatch));
                pendingMatch.clear();
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reduces the current pending match to an actual (partial) match
     * after the addition of the next glyph has invalidated it as a
     * whole match.
     */
    void reduceToPartialMatch() {
        outer:
        while (!pendingMatch.isEmpty()) {
            pendingMatch.remove(0);
            int index = 0;
            for (Glyph glyph : pendingMatch) {
                if (!toRemove.substring(index, index + glyph.text.length()).equals(glyph.text)) {
                    continue outer;
                }
                index++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    String toRemove = null;
    final List<List<PdfObject>> cachedOperations = new LinkedList<>();

    int elementNumber = -1;
    int processedElements = 0;
    final List<Glyph> pendingMatch = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<List<Glyph>> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<List<Glyph>> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Render listener class used by {@link SimpleTextRemover} as listener
     * of its content stream processor ancestor. Essentially it forwards
     * {@link TextRenderInfo} events and ignores all else.
     */
    static class SimpleTextRemoverListener implements RenderListener {
        @Override
        public void beginTextBlock() { }

        @Override
        public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
            simpleTextRemover.renderText(renderInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public void endTextBlock() { }

        @Override
        public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

        SimpleTextRemover simpleTextRemover = null;
    }

    /**
     * Value class representing a glyph with information on
     * the displayed text and its position, the overall number
     * of the string argument of a text showing instruction
     * it is in and the index at which it can be found therein,
     * and the width to use as text position adjustment when
     * replacing it. Beware, the width does not yet consider
     * character and word spacing!
     */
    public static class Glyph {
        public Glyph(TextRenderInfo info, int elementNumber, int index) {
            text = info.getText();
            ascent = info.getAscentLine();
            base = info.getBaseline();
            descent = info.getDescentLine();
            this.elementNumber = elementNumber;
            this.index = index;
            this.width = info.getFont().getWidth(text);
        }

        public final String text;
        public final LineSegment ascent;
        public final LineSegment base;
        public final LineSegment descent;
        final int elementNumber;
        final int index;
        final float width;
    }

    final PdfLiteral OPERATOR_Tasterisk = new PdfLiteral("T*");
    final PdfLiteral OPERATOR_Tc = new PdfLiteral("Tc");
    final PdfLiteral OPERATOR_Tw = new PdfLiteral("Tw");
    final PdfLiteral OPERATOR_Tj = new PdfLiteral("Tj");
    final PdfLiteral OPERATOR_TJ = new PdfLiteral("TJ");
    final static List<String> TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("Tj", "'", "\"", "TJ");
    final static Glyph[] EMPTY_GLYPH_ARRAY = new Glyph[0];
}
```

*([SimpleTextRemover](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/SimpleTextRemover.java#L66) helper class)*

You can use it like this:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, RESULT_STREAM);
SimpleTextRemover remover = new SimpleTextRemover();

System.out.printf("\ntest.pdf - Test\n");
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    System.out.printf("Page %d:\n", i);
    List<List<Glyph>> matches = remover.remove(pdfStamper, i, "Test");
    for (List<Glyph> match : matches) {
        Glyph first = match.get(0);
        Vector baseStart = first.base.getStartPoint();
        Glyph last = match.get(match.size()-1);
        Vector baseEnd = last.base.getEndPoint();
        System.out.printf("  Match from (%3.1f %3.1f) to (%3.1f %3.1f)\n", baseStart.get(I1), baseStart.get(I2), baseEnd.get(I1), baseEnd.get(I2));
    }
}

pdfStamper.close();
```

*([RemovePageTextContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/RemovePageTextContent.java#L54) test `testRemoveTestFromTest`)*

with the following console output for my test file:

```
test.pdf - Test
Page 1:
  Match from (134,8 666,9) to (177,8 666,9)
  Match from (134,8 642,0) to (153,4 642,0)
  Match from (172,8 642,0) to (191,4 642,0)
```

and the occurrences of "Test" missing at those positions in the output PDF.

Instead of outputting the match coordinates, you can use them to draw replacement text at the position in question.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for such elaborate and straight to the point reply

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, it worked like a charm.We are going to draw the replacement text now.

Comment: Great that it works for you! And if there is some PDF it does not work for, see the known limitations above, it likely can be improved to work.

Comment: @mkl We hit a new brick wall, this time due to some issue with fonts, for some reason we can't detect, Arial Narrow doesn't get replaced consistently, if you're willing to spend some more time with us, we opened a new
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587808/why-am-i-getting-extra-symbols-when-replacing-arial-narrow) :)

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file is not a Word Processing file. What you see are explicit placement of characters that are kerned together and/or many other things. your dream to "replace" text in such a way is not possible or better said, not likely if not impossible.

A PDF is a binary file with byte offsets. It have many parts. Like this is at this byte offset and read this, then go that that byte offset and read that.

You cannot just replace "foo" with "foobar" and think that it will work. It would disrupt all byte offsets and break the file completely.

Try it yourself before even asking.

In your example you have above, open the file in some editor and change the string in what you posted from this:

```
This is a
```

to this:

```
WOW Let me change this data around for the content "This is a"
```

Save that file and try an open it. Even that, which is a set string of content not crossing the boundaries you identified will not work. Because it is not a Word Processing file. It is not a text file. It is a binary file that you cannot manipulate as you think you can.