# Why am I getting extra symbols when replacing Arial Narrow?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

I'm using iText in my Java application to replace a certain string in a PDF document. I noticed extra symbols appear when the original font used in the PDF doc was Arial Narrow.

As you can see in the example below, the string `@@[PORTFOLIO-123456789]` was replaced with the string `vlopezbo`. It worked just fine when the font was Arial or Futura. However, in the case of **Arial Narrow**, extra square-like symbols where added to the right after the replacement. Trying to figure out why?

Please notice square symbols on the right

[image]

Comment: Please share the PDF in question before and after replacement. As far as I know there is nothing special about Arial Narrow (in contrast to Arial or Futura) that would explain this behavior. Thus, I assume there is an issue with the original PDF. Also possible is an issue in your code; a look into the result PDF might help to determine that but it may become necessary to share that code, too...

Comment: viclobon, @Steven - have you meanwhile resolved this issue? If not, have you problems providing example files?

Comment: Hi @mkl, thank you so much for your ongoing interest in our questions.  The reason it took us so long this time is that, unfortunately we can't provide you with a pdf due to security restrictions, we generate them through JSON templates and we've tried several approaches to remove all sensitive information for this, but there's no way we can remove all :(

Comment: Hhmm, that sounds unfortunate, without the PDFs I see no starting point for an analysis of the issue.