# How to remove text in file pdf with iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I want to replace a special string in the content of a PDF file.

e.g. I want to replace "111" with "abc".

I 'm using iTextSharp and C#.

Comment: For an approach you may want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57398454/1729265) and port the code from Java to C#. But be aware that the restrictions mentioned in @Joris' answer do apply.

Answer (score 1):

This is (in general) not possible.

PDF is a rendered document. Not a structured document (at least not by default).

**Structured document:**

- the document has information on the content
- e.g. 'this is a paragraph'
- e.g. 'this is a title just below that paragraph'
- etc

**Rendered document:**

- character 'H' is drawn at location 50, 50 in black
- character 'e' is drawn at location 55, 50 in black
- etc

The problem with removing (or adding) content is **reflowing** the content.

Imagine the following text:

> Once upon a midnight dreary,
>   while I pondered weak and weary,
>   over many a quaint and curious volume
>   of forgotten lore.

If I remove the word 'midnight' (in a rendered document), I would get

> Once upon a ________ dreary,
>   while I pondered weak and weary,
>   over many a quaint and curious volume
>   of forgotten lore.

In other words, because the document doesn't contain information about what belongs together (is this a word? paragraph? line?), it can't magically put text back together if you remove something.

You'll encounter a similar problem when you're trying to add text.

I know there is an example on the iText website that replaces a string with another in a PDF document.
The key difference there is that the target and replacement string have roughly the same (rendered) length.
So reflow is not needed.