# Java: How to fix Itext PdfReader not found the method getPageN(int pageNumber)?

Tags: java, pdf, error-handling, itext

Why can't I find **reader.getPageN(1)**? It could not be found from `PdfReader.java` also. How can I fix this?

[image: itext replace]

Comment: You are trying to use iText5 code with iText7 library. Either downgrade your dependency to iText 5.5.13.1 (deprecated version) or adapt your code for iText7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use iText5 code, while using iText7 as a dependency (the API has changed between these two versions).

The good news is that iText has [an example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/itext/i7js-examples/master/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/stamper/ReplaceStream.java) for iText7 with what you are trying to achieve on their [examples repository](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples).

Comment: When I tried to replace a text as the example, and nothing happened except generating that file with a new name...

Comment: here the one: https://jobsgo.vn/uploads/cv/web/2f1470d5b83f1ed908a158406a599a837187097e-1566886719.pdf

Comment: putting it in super simple terms, the text isn't present in the PDF in a way that that code sample will work (it's constructed with a lot of information). To be able to do it, you'd have to follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57398454/1566339